# Can't save child with parent's Id

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have struggled with the relatively simple issue:

In the parent class I map:

```
HasMany(x => x.States)
         .KeyColumn("WorkflowOid")
         .Inverse()
         .Cascade.All()
         .Not.LazyLoad();
```

The DB has the column WorkflowOid in the child table.

In the child mapping class:

```
References(x => x.Workflow)
         .Column("WorkflowOid");
```

Considering a new Workflow object with a State in the "States" list, is there a way to automatically recognize that the parent is the workflow object, without having to set the "Workflow" variable in the child?

I mean, when I save a Workflow object with a State which does not have the Workflow variable set to the parent instance causes the column "WorkflowOid" in the child to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way you currently have it mapped. You have the parent relationship mapped as `Inverse()` meaning that it is not responsible for saving the relationship on the child object.

You do have a `Cascade.All()` set, but the parent is simply calling `SaveOrUpdate()` on the child, the child doesn't have a parent set, so it's saving `null` for the WorkflowOid from it's null `Workflow` property.

Here are some ways to fix this:

1) Have a method on the parent called `AddState(State state)` and when you call it, make it set `state.Workflow = this` as well as adding it to the `States` collection.

2) Make the parent responsible for saving the relationship with the child by removing `Inverse()`, and set the child as `Inverse()` instead, this means that only saving a parent could ever write to the WorflowOid column.

3) Remove `Inverse()` from the parent, and don't link the child to the parent at all, this will mean that on new child **creation only** (but not updates) you would get both a `Save()` (save the child) and `Update()` (add the WorkflowOid to it) event, which is ineffecient, but sometimes having a nicer/more sensible codebase trumps this. Obviously in this case you could only get children via their parents too.

Comment: The suggestion 3 is exactly what I needed. Thank you. I just Added ".Not" before ".Inverse" and removed the reference from the child.